# Can sqlite3 databases be created in a thread-safe way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I would like to save data to sqlite3 databases which will be fetched from the remote system by FTP. Each database would be given a name that is an encoding of the time and date with a resolution of 1 hour (i.e. a new database every hour).

From the Python 3 sqlite3 library, would any problems be encountered if two threads try to create the database at the same time? Or are there protections against this?

Comment: See [Is SQLite threadsafe](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6).

Comment: I've read that already, but it seems to talk only about operations on an existing database. My question is what will happen if the database doesn't exist and then two threads try to create it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work just fine.
When two threads are trying to create the same file, one will fail to do so, but it will continue to try to lock the file.

Comment: So using the .connect method, it will create the file if it's not there and another thread would fail to create it but would still connect once it gets a lock? Just to clarify a bit.